# ActiveMQ CLIENT on Java 1.4

Tags: java, activemq-classic, java1.4

We are using Active MQ in the most current version 5.6.0. 
Now we have the problem that a new client has to be connected, unfortunately this client is developed with IBM JDK 1.4. Adding ActiveMQ to the application lead to the following error:

```
UNEXPECTED ERROR OCCURRED: org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQConnectionFactory (Unsupported major.minor version 50.0) 
STACK TRACE: 
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQConnectionFactory (Unsupported major.minor version 50.0)
```

We don't want to switch to an older ActiveMQ version, since there are other applications using the current version. Now my questions (I know the FAQ and especially http://activemq.apache.org/can-i-use-activemq-5x-or-later-on-java-14.html):

Are there any ActiveMQ client jars which are usable to connect to Active MQ 5.6.0? 
For example is it possible to use an ActiveMQ 4.0 client to connect to Active MQ 5.6.0? 
Is it possible to use any other protocol for this purpose? Has anyone a succesful solution running?

If I have to use retrotranslator which is the minimum set on jars I have to translate? Has anyone the experience with IBM JDK 1.4?

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: I did also ask this on the mailing list: http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/ActiveMQ-client-on-Java-1-4-td4653940.html

Comment: I assume you don't want to migrate the client to a more recent version of Java. JDK 1.4 has been end of life for a few years now (even JDK 6 will be EOL this year)

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible. Code runs inside a Websphere, update means additionally license costs, customer doesn't want this, I can't force him.

Comment: Apart from using retrotranslator, you could create a a gateway service. e.g. have a service which can connect to the desired version of ActiveMQ which communicates with the websphere process in a protocol it supports e.g. RMI or an older version of ActiveMQ.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect from STOMP to the ActiveMQ broker, or you can use an older AMQ 5.x client and connect.  You can of course try an older 4.x client but its not really recommended.  Version 5 clients should be able to connect without much problem however anytime you use an older client you are subject to the issues that are contained in those clients that were fixed in newer releases.

Comment: Is there something like a Java 1.4 STOMP client? I was not able to find one, just a STOMP plugin for ActiveMQ.

Comment: There's none that I know of, but STOMP is dead simple and a client can be written in a day or so.  Take a look at the StompConnect class in the ActiveMQ Stomp unit tests source.

Comment: Just because you don't like the answer doesn't mean its not right.

Comment: :-) Didn't say that it is not right. But there are some STOMP implementations available which support 1.4 or allow easy backport, e.g. http://code.google.com/p/stompj (see http://code.google.com/p/stompj/issues/detail?id=1) or https://github.com/fusesource/stompjms/tree/master/stompjms-client

Answer (score 0):

You might try to build ActiveMQ yourself (or STOMP), from source, [using the `-target 1.4` command line option, and addressing other cross-compile concerns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-example).  Since you have 1.4 libraries available, you should be able to use those in the bootclasspath for the cross-compile.

Cross your fingers, and you may get lucky by not having any hard dependencies on new library elements (nio).  Or you might find ways to work around them.