# Do Apache ActiveMQ client and server have to use the same jar file versions?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

Can clients using v5.10.2 client jar files connect to an ActiveMQ v5.15.5 server?

Based on my research they will both follow the JMS v1.1 spec and so should work, though obviously missing out on some of the improvements in the newer version.

The use case is clients running older versions of Java and therefore limited to older client jar files.

Note: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11611082/1662031) implicitly answers the question but as it's not explicit am leaving my question here for somebody authoritative to answer explicitly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JMS is not a protocol it is an API specification.

ActiveMQ client's use the OpenWire protocol which does offer cross version compatibility so Older 5.x clients should work with newer 5.x brokers.  That said the combinations aren't tested so while in theory it can work in practice it is best to upgrade the clients along with the broker whenever possible.